# NSArray received memory warning

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, nsarray

I have an array of images that changes to a random image with an `IBAction` attached to a button when pressed. When run on a simulator it runs fine but on a device it seems to crash after memory warnings. It also lags when the button is pressed. I want it to run smoothly, and not crash. I believe this has something to do with my array not releasing each image. Here is my array inside my buttons code.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
{

     int ptr = arc4random() % 132;

    NSArray* images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"17",@"29",@"55",@"400",@"Alcohol",@"Arianny",@"Anderson",@"Approach",@"Arab",@"Asian",@"Attitude",@"Attraction",@"Beckinsale",@"Blueberry",@"Brain",@"Break",@"Breakups",@"Burns",@"Buttocks",@"Charity",@"Check",@"Chicago",@"Chocolate",@"Coco",@"Coffee",@"College",@"Commit",@"Common",@"Confident",@"Cook",@"Count",@"Country",@"Couples",@"Courtship",@"Criminal",@"Cruz",@"Date",@"Date14",@"Deed",@"Degree",@"Dropped",@"Dushku",@"Dworaczyk",@"Eating",@"Emotion",@"Exercise",@"Fwb",@"Fantasies",@"Fitness",@"Flings",@"Flirt",@"Foot",@"Forget",@"Friendship",@"Frowning",@"Hum",@"Impression",@"Hair",@"Happiness",@"Hazel",@"Headache",@"Instant",@"Interest",@"Internet",@"Jacobs",@"January",@"Jimena",@"Jolie",@"Kalia",@"Kardashian",@"Kiss",@"Kissing",@"Krupa",@"Larissa",@"Latino",@"Laughter",@"Lip",@"London",@"Love",@"Love2",@"Love3",@"Love4",@"Math",@"Maximus",@"Melany",@"Memory",@"Men",@"Milian",@"Miller",@"Millions",@"Mind",@"Monica",@"Muscle",@"Partner",@"Naps",@"Negativity",@"Novels",@"Oral",@"Ossa",@"Pain",@"Positions",@"Productive",@"Proximity",@"Read",@"Reputation",@"Second",@"Sensitive",@"Serious",@"Shaking",@"Sleep2",@"Smile",@"Smoke",@"Smoke2",@"Smokers",@"Sneeze",@"Socks",@"Sold",@"Spot",@"Stimuli",@"Stone",@"Survey",@"Swell",@"Tattoo",@"Teacher",@"Teeth",@"Vickers",@"Violence",@"Wallet",@"Weight",@"Windmills.png",@"White",@"Women",@"Yawn",nil];


    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:ptr]]];
    ptr++;
    NSLog(@"button pressed");

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.images=nil;

}

- (void)dealloc {

    [images release];
    [adView release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Did you actually type that out by hand?!

Comment: Which versions of iOS are you targeting? Since iOS 6, `viewDidUnload` is never called as views are never unloaded. They release most of their internal storage (though nothing related to public properties) but continue to exist, rather than the view controller dumping the views entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use ARC, if you can.

You have 2 things leaking memory: the image and the array of image names. Since the image names are constant, you only need to create this array once.

Create ivars for the image and for the image name array:
     UIImage *_image;
     NSArray *_imageNames; // init this in your `viewDidLoad:`

Then, in your button press handler:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
{
     int ptr = arc4random() % 132;

    [_image release];
    _image = UIImage imageNamed:_images[ptr]];
    [imageView setImage:_image];
    ptr++;
    NSLog(@"button pressed");
}
```

Finally, release _imageNames:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_imageNames release];
    // release everything else.
}
```

Again, you should really consider switching to ARC. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Thank you. so Do i set up my NSARRay globally the same way I set it up inside the button press handler previously, with all of the string objects listed?

Comment: Yes. The idea is to do it only once, not every time the user presses the button.

Comment: so i would init my string objects in the viewdidload under _imageNames or would I use _image..       _imageNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"17.png",@"29.png",nil]

Comment: Yeah, you can init the array in `viewDidLoad:`. Another common approach is to declare this array as a property, and then initialize it in the getter method.

Comment: If I do that I still do not understand what UIImage*_image is or does I would not need that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what are you asking. `_image` is set inside `buttonPressed:`, right?

Comment: Yea I have button pressed how u displayed it above but globally and in my viewdidload do I have to init each image being used in the array using UIImage or do I just declare it globally like UIImage *_image;
NSArray *_imageNames;...then in view did load like this

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     UIImage *_image;
    _imageNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"17.png",@"29.png",nil];

Answer (score 2):

As I see your code is not running with ARC so when you create images array it is not deleted from memory until you call release. write release after you don't need your array anymore:

```
int ptr = arc4random() % 132;
NSArray* images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"17",@"29"];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:ptr]]];
ptr++;
[images release];
```

Comment: Yes that's right and I think that he has property named images, which is never used, so he can just create it once and release it only when is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two problems here, both surrounding this line:

```
NSArray* images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: ...strings omitted... ,nil];
```

The first is that the `NSArray*` at the beginning of the line declares a new local variable, `images`. This is separate from the property `self.images` that you try to erase in `-viewDidUnload` and release in `-dealloc`. Removing the `NSArray*` from the line will fix this issue, storing the array into the `self.images` property as you seem to intend.

That gives you a line like this:

```
images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: ...strings omitted... ,nil];
```

The second problem is that you re-create the `images` array each time you go through this method. That means that, even if you fixed the first problem, you would still be throwing away the old array without releasing it each time you passed through the method, so you'd still be leaking these arrays. There are a bunch of ways you could fix this, but the easiest one is probably to simply test if you already have an array and only create it if you haven't:

```
if(!images) {
    images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: ...strings omitted... ,nil];
}
```

(Since all instances of this class have an identical list of image names, you could instead store the array in a static variable so it'd be shared between them—perhaps initialized by calling `dispatch_once`—but this isn't likely to make a difference unless you have many instances of this view controller on screen at the same time.)